# I want to convert an output stream into String object

Tags: java, jaxb

I want to convert an `OutputStream` into a `String` object. I am having an `OutputStream` object returned after marshalling the JAXB object.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

not very familiar with jaxb, from what i was able to find you can convert into a string using

```java
public String asString(JAXBContext pContext, 
                        Object pObject)
                            throws 
                                JAXBException {

    java.io.StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

    Marshaller marshaller = pContext.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    marshaller.marshal(pObject, sw);

    return sw.toString();
}
```

[ws.apache.org](http://ws.apache.org/jaxme/release-0.4/manual/ch02s02.html)

but I'm not sure about a stirng object. still searching.

** EDIT

> Marshalling a non-element
>
> Another common use case is where you
>   have an object that doesn't have
>   @XmlRootElement on it. JAXB allows you
>   to marshal it like this:
>
> marshaller.marshal( new JAXBElement(
>   new
>   QName("","rootTag"),Point.class,new
>   Point(...)));
>
> This puts the  element as the
>   root element, followed by the contents
>   of the object, then . You
>   can actually use it with a class that
>   has @XmlRootElement, and that simply
>   renames the root element name.
>
> At the first glance the second
>   Point.class parameter may look
>   redundant, but it's actually necessary
>   to determine if the marshaller will
>   produce (infamous) @xsi:type. In this
>   example, both the class and the
>   instance are Point, so you won't see
>   @xsi:type. But if they are different,
>   you'll see it.
>
> This can be also used to marshal a
>   simple object, like String or an
>   integer.
>
> marshaller.marshal( new JAXBElement(
>   new
>   QName("","rootTag"),String.class,"foo
>   bar"));
>
> But unfortunately it cannot be used to
>   marshal objects like List or Map, as
>   they aren't handled as the first-class
>   citizen in the JAXB world.

found [HERE](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2005/10/13/101-ways-marshal-objects-jaxb)

Comment: Just making a note here that StringWriter approach indeed works. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

```
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    com.integra.xml.Integracao integracao = new Integracao();
    integracao.add(...);
try {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.integra.xml");
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.marshal(integracao, sw );
    System.out.println(sw.toString());
} catch (JAXBException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: cleanest approach so far

Answer (score 1):

```
public String readFile(String pathname) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(pathname);
    StringBuilder fileContents = new StringBuilder((int) file.length());
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    try {
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            fileContents.append(scanner.nextLine() + lineSeparator);
        }
        return fileContents.toString();
    }
    finally {
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Method to handle the XML and convert it to a string.

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ClassMatchingStartofXMLTags.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    //store filepath to be used
    String filePath = "YourXMLFile.xml";
    File xmlFile = new File(filePath);
    //Set up xml Marshaller
    ClassMatchingStartofXMLTags xmlMarshaller = (ClassMatchingStartofXMLTags) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlFileEdit);
    Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    // Use marshall to output the contents of the xml file
    System.out.println("Marshalled XML\n");
    marshaller.marshal(xmlMarshaller, System.out); 
    //Use Readfile method to convert the XML to a string and output the results
    System.out.println("\nXML to String");
    String strFile = ReadFile(xmlFile)
    System.out.println(strFile);
```

Method within your class to get the XML and Marshall it
*Edit* The above method will both output the marshalled xml and also the xml as a string.

Comment: This is extremely convoluted, and isn't clear or proper Java. The original author doesn't necessarily have an XML file in hand; the question referred to an OutputStream.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to do it: just pass the String writer as input to it. So that it the xml created will be written to it

```java
   public void saveSettings() throws IOException {
       FileOutputStream os = null;
       //Declare a StringWriter to which the output has to go
       StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
       try {
           Answer ans1=new Answer(101,"java is a programming language","ravi");  
           Answer ans2=new Answer(102,"java is a platform","john");  

           ArrayList<Answer> list=new ArrayList<Answer>();  
           list.add(ans1);  
           list.add(ans2);  

           settings=new Question(1,"What is java?",list); 
           os = new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME);
           this.marshaller.marshal(settings, new StreamResult(sw));
           System.out.println(sw.toString());
           new File(FILE_NAME).delete();
       } finally {
           if (os != null) {
               os.close();
           }
       }
   }
```