# Getting Marshall result into String

Tags: java, jaxb

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext
                    .newInstance(CreateExemptionCertificate.class);
            Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

            m.marshal(cc, System.out);
```

In the code above i am getting the result to the console (I mean XML is getting printed on the console). I want to get this XML to a string. I am not getting which argument I should pass to the marshal method to get XML String in a String variable instead of printing it on the console. Anybody having any idea please share.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to convert an output stream into String object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472155/i-want-to-convert-an-output-stream-into-string-object)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just now I have got the answer of my question from this post below:

[I want to convert an output stream into String object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472155/i-want-to-convert-an-output-stream-into-string-object)

I need to use StringWriter to take XML String from Marshal method

Answer (score 83):

You can do it like this :

```
CreateExemptionCertificate cc = ...;
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(CreateExemptionCertificate.class);
Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
m.marshal(cc, sw);

String result = sw.toString();
```

Answer (score 7):

Try marshalling to an instance of [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) and then invoking [`toByteArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toByteArray%28%29) on it.

Comment: What do you want to do with it? The approach I proposed (calling `toByteArray()` on the stream) would give you a `byte[]` instance containing the bytes of the XML.

Comment: Im having the same need, in my case I'm trying to returning it as a result of service call.

Answer (score 0):

This is the parser I use for convert an object to string using jaxb library.

```js
 JAXBElement<Foo> jaxbElement = new JAXBElement<>(
                new QName(Foo.class.getSimpleName()), Foo.class, request);
        JAXBContext contextRS = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);
        String requestXml = lhParser.marshalAndConvertToString(jaxbElement, contextRS);


//converter

    public String marshalAndConvertToString(JAXBElement jaxbElement, JAXBContext context) {
        try {
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            context.createMarshaller().marshal(jaxbElement, writer);
            String s = writer.toString();
            LOG.info(" ------------------------ xml \n{}",s );
            return s;
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```